# Python xml tree structure

Tags: python, xml, celementtree

How can I follow a way to print data in doc tag in each loop?

My code

```
root = ET.Element("root")
doc = ET.SubElement(root, "doc")
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
for row in tree.iter():
    ET.SubElement(doc, "sku", name="sku").text = siradakiSku
    ET.SubElement(doc, "baslik", name="baslik").text = urunBaslik
    tree.write("C:/Users/s/Desktop/ferodo/veri.xml")
```

my export result:

```
<root>
<doc>
   <sku name="sku">ART1000</sku>
   <baslik name="baslik">DIS DIKIZ AYNA</baslik>
   <sku name="sku">ART2000</sku>
   <baslik name="baslik">DIS DIKIZ AYNASI MEKANIK</baslik>
</doc>
</root>
```

I want to print the data to xml file as follows:

```
<root>
<doc>
   <Sku>ART1000</Sku>
   <baslik>DIS DIKIZ AYNA</baslik>
</doc>
<doc>
   <Sku>ART2000</Sku>
   <baslik>DIS DIKIZ AYNASI MEKANIK</baslik>
</doc>
</root>
```

Comment: You would need to create a new `doc` element in your loop (as a subelement of your root element). Right now you're creating the `doc` element outside your loop so there is only a single one.

Comment: resolved thank you very much

Comment: Please mark this question as resolved